# Why hasn't the site awarded me the Curious, Inquisitive or Socratic badges?

Tags: support, badges

I complained about this in the chat and to my chagrin, after finding out **I DO have a positive question score**, that my best hope was to keep trying at it. Considering that was almost 100 questions ago, I don't think it's going to fix itself and that the badge is bugged.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder what “positive question record” means exactly?

@Brythan noted [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234963/give-users-a-way-to-see-their-positive-question-record-score) which gives a formula that is approximate or an early draft or something like that.

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

You have 189 questions if you look at your Rep page, but the badge counter is 101. So a rough estimate is that 101 are the good ones, but good÷total is 0.53. That’s close enough to 0.5 that it’s worth considering that the exact value used for “positive question record” including nuances such as how multiple questions (especially good and bad) on the same day are handled, is coming out on the *low* side of the cutoff.

So, take care to ask more *good* questions and the badges will trigger after the balance tips.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, you have not maintained a positive question record.

The formula is:

$$\frac{(\text{total}_q - \text{negative}_q - \text{closed}_q - \text{deleted}_q)}{\text{total}_q} \geq 0.5$$

So a negative, closed & deleted question counts against you three times! I do see on your profile a lot of deleted questions (~40 or so, and the list on there only retains about 1 year's worth). It seems that our WB SEDE queries do NOT retain deleted questions yet, so I can't pull that data in, but that's the most likely explanation.

Comment: I think SEDE data doesn't include deleted posts, period.